# Number of ways to make n digit number?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given M digits which are between 1 to 9,
Find the number of ways to form N digit number, by repeating one or more given digits such that each of M digits are present in N digit number at least once.
Example if M = 3 and N = 4
Answer is 36.

Explanation -  let the three digits be 1 2 3
our N = 4, digit number can be 1123, 3211, 1132, ..... repeating 1
similarly repeating 2 and three we will get the total ans.

Since answer is large find the ans % 10000000007.
1 ≤ M ≤ N ≤ 100.

Comment: Is this a project Euler problem?

Comment: nope its from a contest that was held in September, 
https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/4214486/dashboard#s=p0

Comment: For each specific case (at least small ones) I'd recommend inclusion-exclusion. However, I am not too familiar with coding contest problems, so I don't know what methods would work well there (you'd need to handle more general cases, but you have more number-crunching ability compared to the common by-hand problem)

Comment: Do the repeated digits have to be adjacent? In your examples, you include 1123 and 3211, but not for example 1231.

Comment: Non mathematical way would be dp+bitmask.
the dp is like plugging characters to the right and setting on the digits that have been used. That assuming that M<10.

Comment: @rogerl no there is no such condition

Comment: @Phicar can you explain the dp + bit mask in detail?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly it is a familiar problem, equivalent to the problem
of counting the number of $N$-letter words from an alphabet of size $M$,
with the restriction that each letter is used at least once.

The well-known answer is $M!S(N,M)$, where $S(N,M)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind,
counting the number of ways to partition $[N]$ in $M$ parts.
You can find references about these Stirling numbers like recursive formulas
and generating functions all over the place if you actually need to write a program
that produces the answer for concrete values of $M$ and $N$.

Btw, a Java implementation using a simple summation for these Stirling numbers calculates
e.g. $S(200,100)$ in a fraction of a second (although it has over 200 digits), so performance cannot be a problem for the values you mention.